# Could not build module 'nanopb'

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I know this has been answered previously on Stack however, the reason for this was outdated cocoapods (not being at least version 1.2.0)

I am currently running version 1.9.3 and using Xcode 12 Beta-3 and still getting this error.

I have done the usual steps to see if the following will solve the issue;

- Cleaned Build Folder
- Restarted Xcode
- Updated Cocoapods
- Checked Cocoapods is on latest version

I believe this is a module pulled in along with Firebase/Firestore although i'm not sure how to check and resolve this issue.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64310532/could-not-build-module-nanopb-error-in-xcode-12-0-1/64320447

Answer (score 3):

It appears I've solved this by deleting the podfile completely and re-initialising a new one then running pod install.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it changing the pubspec.yaml

**Replacing**
version: 1.0.1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

**To**
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: This response is not related with the question.