# Could not build module 'nanopb' error in Xcode 12.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I upgraded my Xcode to 12. Everything was working perfectly and all of a sudden I kept getting bellow error message (Image below)

[image]

[image]

SO link have tried using to solve this issue

[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084390/could-not-build-module-nanopb)

**What I've done so far**

- Cleaned Build Folder
- Restarted Xcode
- Updated Cocoapods
- Deleted DerivedData
- Cleared pod cache
- Deleted pods directory and file and reinstall

None of them worked and its getting frustrating.

**Pod file**

[image]

Comment: If Im not mistaken, that gets installed as part of firebase.  You should be able to run ‘pod repo update’ then ‘pod install’ and it should take care of it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

All I did was to follow the instruction(see image below) and it got fixed.

[Source here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987)

[image]

Comment: You saved my day :) ,, Thank you very much .. only your solution solves the problem after a huge numbers of trials

Comment: @yasmeensoubhi I'm glad it helped. Kindly give me an upvote :-). Thanks

Comment: Turning off warnings doesn't seem like a solution to me. `pod upgrade' as per @f-perroch's answer is though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a project still targeting iOS 8 as the minimum iOS version. This steps solved my problem:

1. Update minimum target iOS version to iOS 9 on `Podfile` file;
2. Open terminal on project folder, remove all pod file dependencies and update them by running:

```
rm -rf /Pods
pod repo update
pod install
```

3. Update minimum project target iOS version to iOS 9;
4. Remove `DerivedData`;
5. Clean project;
6. Compile/run project again.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to update **cocoapods** to the **1.10** version

First, update the CocoaPods installation :
`[sudo] gem install cocoapods`

Then, update your project : `bundle update cocoapods`

Finally, run `pod install` and everything should be OK :)

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This issue CAN be the result of developing iOS on an **M1 (Apple Silicon) machine**. In this case, the only way to fix the problem is to download a Ruby extension called "**ffi**" which you can read about here (for extra information): https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi/versions/1.0.9

To do this:

In Terminal, install ffi onto your machine using this command:

**sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**

Then in your project file, install your podfile with this command:

**arch -x86_64 pod install**

This should allow you to install your pods (especially if you were getting a "**zsh: abort** pod install" problem. Notice Terminal will warn you "a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries".

After this, if your pod was FireStore/FireBase you may have to get another **GoogleService-Info.plist** file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If the previous solutions did not help someone, then try changing it this way:

`#include <nanopb/pb.h>`

**->**

`#include "nanopb/pb.h"`

Comment: Did not work for me.